# Importing specific rows and columns from a CSV with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import

```
require 'csv'    

CSV.foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
  if column3 = true || column 4 = true
    Model.create!(row.to_hash)
  else
    skip
  end
end
```

First, is there a way to only grab certain columns during the `row.to_hash`?

Second, is my use of the `if` statement the best way to grab particular rows?
Could I just load the entire CSV to some sort of staging table of sorts, and then grab what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`row.to_hash` will produce a hash of attributes based on the headers.  To select a particular set of attributes, you should use slice.

```
>> row.to_hash # { :attr1 => 'val1', :attr2 => 'val2', :attr3 => 'val3' }
>> row.to_hash.slice(:attr1, :attr2) # { :attr1 => 'val1', :attr2 => 'val2' }
```

About your second question: YES, you still need to load the entire csv and just check against each row.